# Will Oracle create a set of UI controls that look native on Windows 8?

Tags: java, user-interface, windows-8

From what I know there is no way to write a native Windows 8 application (with Metro style) in Java. Will it be create in Java 8 or there is already a set of UI (User Interface) controls that look native on Windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that Oracle will do this.  Conforming with the native look-and-feel is not on the agenda for Swing.  (Or at least, it never has been in the past.)

I you want to build a Java UI that has the look-and-feel of the native windowing system, take a look at [SWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit).  I don't think Windows 8 look-and-feel is supported yet, but I would expect this to be in the pipeline.

According to some stuff I've seen, a port of Java was not available for the Windows 8 early / developer releases.  This would have made porting the Eclipse ecosystem ... including SWT ... to Windows 8 difficult.

According to the Oracle website:

- Java supports Windows 8 as a certified platform from jdk-1.7.0_u10.  That was only released in December 2012.
- Java on Windows 8 doesn't (yet) run on Metro.  (Or if it does run, it is not certified.)

Answer (score 1):

> From what I know there is no way to write a native Windows 8 application (with Metro style) in Java.

That's correct.

> Will it be created in Java 8...

Microsoft controlls how Metro works, not Oracle

> or there is already a set of UI (User Interface) controls that look native on Windows 8?

I found this with a Google search: [JMetro – Windows 8 Metro controls on Java](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jmetro-%E2%80%93-windows-8-metro).  I'm sure there are others.

In my opinion, Windows 8 Metro controls are a step backwards in usability.